# Une chose est-elle « cohérente avec » une autre ?

Tags: traduction, prépositions, adjectifs, formulation

> Selon la Coalition pour les droits égaux, toute personne a droit au
>   respect de ses droits fondamentaux, sans distinction. Nous pressons le
>   gouvernement du Brunei à abolir les nouvelles peines et à s’assurer
>   que toute mesure introduite **est cohérente avec** les obligations et
>   les engagements internationaux du pays en matière de droits de la
>   personne.
>
> ---
>
> The ERC affirms that all people are entitled to respect for their
>   human rights, without distinction.  We urge the government of Brunei
>   to repeal the new penalties, and to ensure that any measures that are
>   introduced **are consistent with** Brunei’s international human rights
>   obligations and commitments.
>
> [*Déclaration de la Coalition pour les droits égaux sur la situation
>   au Brunei*](https://www.canada.ca/fr/affaires-mondiales/nouvelles/2019/04/declaration-de-la-coalition-pour-les-droits-egaux-sur-la-situation-au-brunei.html)

Des choses peuvent *être cohérentes*, *former un tout cohérent*, *être cohérentes entre elles* etc.

- Une chose peut-elle être [*cohérente*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/coh%C3%A9rent) [*avec*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/avec) une autre (*une mesure être cohérente avec les obligations*) ?
- Quelle formulation est la plus naturelle en français dans le contexte
  de la déclaration ?
- Quelle traduction de [*consistent with*](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/consistent/571977?q=consistent%20with#821935) aurait été meilleure le
  cas échéant ?

Comment: Dans ce contexte, 'compatible' peut aller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oui, « cohérent avec » est la manière idiomatique de formuler cette idée. Dire qu'une chose est *cohérente* avec une autre revient à dire que si on les met ensemble, elles forment un tout *cohérent*.

Il y a peut-être un peu de méfiance parce que cette formulation [est devenue un peu plus répandue dans la deuxième moitié du 20<sup>e</sup> siècle](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=coh%C3%A9rent+avec%2Fcoh%C3%A9rent&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28coh%C3%A9rent%20avec%20/%20coh%C3%A9rent%29%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C(coh%C3%A9rent%20avec%20%2F%20coh%C3%A9rent)%3B%2Cc0). Mais ce n'est pas une formulation nouvelle. On la trouve par exemple dans un [mémoire de société médicale de 1801](https://books.google.fr/books?id=WPcEAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA421&dq=%22coh%C3%A9rent+avec%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjps6_bg9ThAhXs0eAKHTaUAko4ChDoAQhDMAM#v=onepage&q=%22coh%C3%A9rent%20avec%22&f=false) (« cela n'est pas cohérent avec le résultat de nos observations »). La formulation a même l'aval explicite de l'Académie française puisqu'on la trouve dans [la neuvième édition du *Dictionnaire*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/coh%C3%A9rent) dans l'expression idiomatique « être cohérent avec soi-même ».

Un commentaire suggère d'utiliser *compatible* plutôt que *cohérent*. Ces mots sont synonymes dans cet usage, mais pas interchangeables. Dans le contexte, *cohérent* convient mieux. Dire qu'une mesure est *compatible* avec des engagements a un sens purement technique : cela signifie que la mesure est légale, qu'elle est conforme à la lettre des lois et règlements qui constituent ces engagements. Dire qu'une mesure est *cohérente* avec des engagements a une connotation morale : cela signifie que la mesure est compatible non seulement avec la lettre mais aussi avec l'esprit des engagements en question. Si les engagements sont des déclarations d'intention et non des règlements précis, *compatible* n'engage pas grand-chose, alors que *cohérent* a une portée significative.

Comment: Y a-t-il une nuance entre la formulation la plus naturelle et la meilleure traduction ? Ou _être cohérent avec_ est-elle une bonne traduction de _to be consistent with_ ?

Comment: @Survenant9r7 Je ne vois pas de meilleure traduction.

Comment: Il y a aussi *être en cohérence avec* ou alors, mais le sens est légèrement différent: *être en accord avec*, *être conforme à*, *être en conformité avec*.

Comment: @jlliagre moi je vois une nuance avec _être cohérent avec_ mais pas nécessairement avec _to be consistent with_, d'où mon dilemme dans l'analyse. Par exemple j'ai regardé comment le gouvernement du Canada rend la formulation dans ses traductions et c'est très variable. On a aussi des verbes avec des sens se rapprochant peut-être davantage de _to comply with_, voire de conforme. Je trouve que c'est un sujet vraiment difficile. J'ai longuement réfléchi à la section traduction de l'entrée [_consistent_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/consistent#Translations) de Wiktionnaire. Je réfléchis encore.