# Une « personne » est-elle « cohérente avec/dans » une chose qui lui est sienne (ses propos/ses propos précédents) ?

Tags: sens, prépositions, adjectifs, formulation

Comme on l'a vu dans le cadre d'une autre [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/34786), des choses peuvent *être cohérentes avec* d'autres choses et on peut aussi [*être cohérent avec soi-même*](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/coh%C3%A9rent/17014/locution?q=coh%C3%A9rent#178370). Reste à savoir si familièrement une « personne » peut être [cohérente](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/coh%C3%A9rent) avec des choses, en particulier ses faits et gestes, plus spécifiquement ses propres propos...

> Cette personne est cohérente avec ses propos.
>  Cette personne est
>   cohérente avec ses propos précédents.
>  Cette personne est
>   cohérente dans ses propos.
>  [Cette personne est cohérente/fait preuve de cohérence quand elle s'exprime.]

- Ces (3) formulations sont-elles toutes claires et cohérentes (la
  quatrième sert à indiquer qu'on n'exprimerait pas son sens dans les
  trois premières) ?
- Ces (3) formulations ont-elles toutes le même sens ; quel est-il ; ces formules reflètent-t-elles une relation entre une personne et une
  chose, entre un comportement de la personne et cette même chose ou finalement entre deux choses par métonymie ou autrement et l'adjectif *cohérent* est-il adéquat pour l'exprimer sinon quel adjectif ou formulation choisirait-on ?

Answer (score 3):

Selon moi, on ne peut exprimer la cohérence entre deux objets complexes sans les définir. On peut exprimer l'équivalence entre deux objets, implicitement l'un par rapport à l'autre, lorsqu'ils sont en adéquation. En d'autres termes, « ses propos » permettent de caractériser « cette personne ».

> Cette personne est en adéquation avec ses propos.

« en adéquation avec ses propos » est l'attribut du sujet de « cette personne ».

Les expressions mentionnées sont difficiles à comprendre parce que l'expression « cette personne est cohérente » est ambigüe.

La personne est cohérente lorsqu'elle s'exprime ?

La personne est cohérente parce qu'elle s'exprime de façon cohérente ?

La personne est cohérente dans son expression ?

La personne est cohérente dans des propos la concernant ?

...

> Cette personne est cohérente dans ses propos.
>
> Dans ses propos, cette personne est cohérente.
>
> Cette personne est cohérente.

L'adjectif qualificatif « cohérente » a une fonction d'attribut du sujet et l'expression « dans ses propos » a une fonction de complément de phrase.

Le sens de « cohérent » est limité, précis mais la cohérence peut être complexe à percevoir.

Answer (score 2):

No 3 est assez clair, signifiant "ses propos sont cohérents". Chaque partie de ce qu'elle dit est cohérente avec le reste de ses propos. On utilisera aussi incohérent en médecine pour des gens qui tiennent des propos sans logique ou déconnectés du monde.

Mais 1 et 2 sont problématiques. Est-ce une cohérence entre ce qu'elle dit et fait ("faites ce que je dis, pas ce que je fais") ou bien toute une vie (vue comme un ensemble d'actions) ou bien rien de bien particulier ?

Answer (score 1):

"Cette personne est cohérente dans ses propos" is a frequently used expression meaning " cette personne tient des propos cohérents".

The context could be : the person is questionned by the police regarding its deeds on a particular day and gives/does not give  coherent answers/ explanations; the person seems to suffer from mental/ emotional disorder but the doctor notices that she is however " cohérente dans ses propos"

"Cette personne est cohérente avec ses propos actuels / avec ses précédents propos / avec ses propos habituals" would certainly be understood and would not be criticized in ordinary discussions. i mean criticizing theses expressions, used in *oral language* , would seem pedantic in ordinary contexts.

Rigorously speaking however , the coherence relation does not hold between a person and his/her words.

Only a person's deeds/ words can be coherent / incoherent whith his/her words. So it would sound better to say :

- " Les actes de cette personne  sont / ne sontpas cohérents avec ses discours/ paroles".
- " la vie de cette personne est cohérente avec ses propos"
- " cette personne mets ses actions en accord avec ses paroles"
- " Ce que dit cette personne n'est pas cohérent avec ses propos précédents."

There is, so to say, a " category mistake" in saying " une personne cohérente avec ses propos".